# how to make django serve non static js files?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

My python backend server serves a react application as static files.
In react, everything inside the src directory is bundled when we build the app, however, there is one javascript file outside the src, in the public directory, that I left there because I want to be untouched after the build. the reason I did this, is because inside the src code, I create Workers, and to create workers we have to specify the url of the worker file. This file is called worker.js, it remains untouched after the build, but after deploying the backend, the frontend cannot access the /worker.js url because apparently django only serves static files, so /worker.js is not recognized and the index.html is returned instead. How can I make it possible to access this non-static js file?

Comment: I don't understand. The definition of "static" is that the file **as-is** is served to your browser, versus dynamic where the response is _calculated/constructed_ (what django views do). So how you describe it, "worker.js" is just another static file. Also "django only serves static files" is not true, actually django is **not supposed to serve static files at all** except in development mode.

Comment: You can put your static files (including worker.js) in any directories you want. If it's inside a `static/` directory inside one of your django apps, django will find it, just make sure the url to access it is prefixed with your `STATIC_URL`. If it's inside any other directory in your project, add that directory to `STATICFILES_DIRS` so django can find it. In development that's all. In production, after you `collectstatic` all your static files are copied into `STATIC_ROOT` where you need to make sure your web server (apache/nginx) finds them (because Django **does not serve static files**).

Comment: "just make sure the url to access it is prefixed with your STATIC_URL" can you clarify this please?

Comment: well since worker.js **is a** static file, it needs to be fetched with a url starting with "/static/" (assuming STATIC_URL = "/static/"), e.g. "/static/root-js/worker.js". "root-js/" is a folder in one of the static directories where you put the worker.js (you can name it whatever you want, it must not conflict with other folders inside other static folders) and can be another folder than where you have the other js files.

Comment: Right. What is happening then is that the webpack build generates a "static" folder and other files that were not bundled. my STATIC-ROOT is this static folder, so the other files are being ignored. can I add both the static folder and its parent folder as STATICFILES_DIRS or is it going to conflict? I dont want to manually add the worker.js inside the static folder all the time

Comment: ok, assumption: we're talking about a deployed environment (i.e. static files not served by django), right? collectstatic will copy all static files (not just js, also css and images) into STATIC_ROOT. Then webpack should put any packaged js also into that same STATIC_ROOT (in its own subfolder). That way your web server can find all files directly inside one location, STATIC_ROOT. Note that's **outside or your project/code directory**!!! worker.js can be anywhere you want as long as it's in one of the folders listed in STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: Inside all your static folders (the ones inside your code/project directory), including the ones inside your apps, you **namespace** in order to avoid conflicts. e.g inside the app "blog" you would put static files in the folder blog/static/blog (repeat blog to namespace), so that when copied into STATIC_ROOT, they end up in STATIC_ROOT/blog. If you have a /static folder in your main project (added in STATICFILES_DIRS) and want to put worker.js there, namespace first, i.e. put it in /static/root_js/ so it will end up in STATIC_ROOT/root_js/worker.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation of how static files work:

## Development

Let's get this to work in a development situation first (django is serving your static files using runserver). STATIC_ROOT is not relevant in this case.

Django can find all your static files from these locations:

- Any /static/ folder located inside your apps, e.g. if you have a `blog` app, then the folder `/blog/static/` will be parsed.
- Any folder specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, so for example if you have an `assets` folder in your main project, you'd add it to `STATICFILES_DIRS` with `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")` where `BASE_DIR` is the location of *manage.py*.

What if both the `blog` app and your assets directory need a "logo.png"? Instead of worrying that images, js files, css files have unique names, use namespacing. Inside the `blog` app, put all static files in `/blog/static/blog/` so when using them you need to refer to `/blog/logo.png` and you know for sure it's going to be the right logo.png. Inside the main project, put the files in `assets/assets` (or call this `static/assets` instead) so you can refer to `/assets/logo.png` for the main assets of your project.

Now if you set `STATIC_URL = "/static/"`, this tells django that all static files urls are prefixed with "/static/", i.e. the logo above can be retrieved with "/static/assets/logo.png" and "/static/blog/logo.png". This is required, since it allows to differentiate a url to a static file from urls that Django routes to views.

In practice, in your templates, you'll use `{% static 'blog/logo.png' %}` so you don't have to hard-code `STATIC_URL` everywhere.

Now enters webpack. It needs to put its packages assets in any of the above directories, or in its own directory that you **also add to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Let's assume the latter: We also have a `/webpack/webpack/` folder in our project that's defined in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, so all webpack assets will be accessed via the url prefix "/static/webpack/".

The worker.js file should be in "assets/assets" and inside your other scripts, if you refer to it via url (to fetch it with an HTTP request), you should refer to it via "/static/assets/worker.js" or using a relative url "../assets/worker.js".

## Production

After you deploy, you don't serve your static files with Django anymore but with a webserver, e.g. Apache or nginx. You configure the web server to recognise any request starting with the `STATIC_URL` ("/static/") and fetch the corresponding file from `STATIC_ROOT`.

So the first thing to do is to copy all the static files of your django app into a folder/location that's reachable by your web server. That location is **outside of your project folder**.

Set `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)), 'static'))`, which points it to a "static" directory in the parent folder of your project.

Then run `python manage.py collectstatic`.

This will copy all static files into this new static folder outside of your project. You'll see:

```
path/to/dir/
   |_ static/
   |   |_ blog/
   |   |   |_ logo.png
   |   |_ assets/
   |   |   |_ logo.png
   |   |   |_ worker.js
   |   |_ webpack/
   |       |_ some_file.js
   |_ django_project/
       |_ manage.py
       |_ main_app/
       |    |_ settings.py
       |_ assets/
       |    |_ assets/
       |        |_ worker.js
       |_ blog/
       |   |_ static/
       |       |_ blog/
       ...
```

Now when your web server sees the url "/static/assets/worker.js" it will return the file in "path/to/dir/static/assets/worker.js".

If you let your production server build the webpack files instead of committing them to your source (i.e. they are not inside "django_project"), then you should configure webpack to put them in the correct location "path/to/dir/static/webpack/" because that's where your web server will be looking for them.

Imagine now you move everything to a 3rd party storage provider. You then only have to do two things:

- Install and configure the storage backend for that storage provider so that Django knows how to read/write files there (with `collecstatic`). This might include setting `STATIC_ROOT`, e.g. `STATIC_ROOT = https://my-bucket.my-storage-provider.com/static`.
- Set `STATIC_URL` to the URL of the storage provider, e.g. `STATIC_URL = https://my-bucket.some_cdn.com/`. Here we point to the CDN which you've configured to know where to fetch the files from.

That's all, everything continues to work.